# UNOCONV failing to convert files in PHP on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, centos7, shell-exec, unoconv

I have UNOCONV library installed on my CentOS 7.3.16.11. When I run file conversion from CLI it works fine, and I'm getting PDF document back: 
`unoconv -d spreadsheet --format=pdf -o temp/ ./document.docx`

But when I try to execute it from PHP 5.6.29, it doesn't give me any output PDF. I'm getting an error from Python environment:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 1196, in <module>
run()
File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 1108, in run
office_environ(of)
File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 202, in office_environ
os.environ['PATH'] = realpath(office.basepath, 'program') + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in \__getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PATH'`

Checked the paths in my environment with:
`echo $PATH`
The output is:
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/username/.local/bin:/home/username/bin`

What can be wrong with running UNOCONV from php?

Comment: There's no PATH set up for the user running php.

Answer (score 1):

Beside figuring out how to set PATH properly while using php you may hack the unoconv script and change line 1174 from

`os.environ['PATH'] = realpath(office.basepath, 'program') + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']`

to

`os.environ['PATH'] = realpath(office.basepath, 'program') + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH'] if 'PATH' in os.environ.keys() else ''`

Comment: the current version of unoconv available at github handles this issue in a similar way.